# How draw pie diagram from json data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use d3 libray version5.

I try draw pie diagram. My data storage in json object. Please help me. Live demo [is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/bgy39kjt/46/)

My javascript code:

```
const data = [
    {id: 0, label: 'qqqqq', percent: 50},
  {id: 1, label: 'wwww', percent: 30},
  {id: 2, label: 'eeeee', percent: 20}
];

const svg = d3.select("#segmentsGraph"),
      width = 250,
      height = 250,
      radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
      g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

const pie = d3.pie()
.sort(null)
.value(function(d) { return d.label; });

const path = d3.arc()
.outerRadius(radius - 10)
.innerRadius(0);

const label = d3.arc()
.outerRadius(radius - 40)
.innerRadius(radius - 40);

data.forEach((d) => {
    console.log(d);

  const arc = g.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(data))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");          

  arc.append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.percent); });

  arc.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")"; })
    .attr("dy", "0.35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.percent; });  
});
```

I searched for the documentation and found the following [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235). But this example not worked in jsfiddle...

Comment: have a real close look at your code and the example, what is `this.segments`.

Comment: @rioV8 sorry, i update question

Comment: how many pie graphs do you want to draw? You probably see only one (1) but you try N (3), that is because of the `join` pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have [changed your code](http://jsfiddle.net/bgy39kjt/47/) to draw a pie:

```js
const data = [
        {id: 0, label: 'qqqqq', percent: 50},
    {id: 1, label: 'wwww', percent: 30},
    {id: 2, label: 'eeeee', percent: 20}
    ];

    const svg = d3.select("#segmentsGraph"),
        width = 250,
        height = 250,
        radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
        g = svg.attr("height", height).attr("width", width).append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);
    
    const pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.percent; });

    const path = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

    const label = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 40)
    .innerRadius(radius - 40);

    
    const arc = g.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");          

    arc.append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.id); });

    arc.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")"; })
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        .text(function(d) {  return d.data.percent; });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.js"></script>
  <svg id="segmentsGraph"></svg>
```

You should use a numeric value in d3.pie().value() method. It will create a new dataset mapping the proportion of d.value and the sum of all d.value to angles. I recommend you to run a console.log(arc.data()) for a better understanding of your new dataset.

You don't need to iterate over your data using forEach because data().enter() does it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use latest d3 its working..

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Testing Pie Chart</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?2.1.3"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.geom.js?2.1.3"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.layout.js?2.1.3"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .slice text {
            font-size: 16pt;
            font-family: Arial;
        }   
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var w = 300,                     
    h = 300,                           
    r = 100,                          
    color = d3.scale.category20c();    

    data = [{"label":"one", "value":20}, 
            {"label":"two", "value":50}, 
            {"label":"three", "value":30}];
    
    var vis = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg:svg")       
        .data([data])                 
            .attr("width", w)       
            .attr("height", h)
        .append("svg:g")             
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")")  

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()        
        .outerRadius(r);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()      
        .value(function(d) { return d.value; });   

    var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")   
        .data(pie)                        
        .enter()                          
            .append("svg:g")           
                .attr("class", "slice");  

        arcs.append("svg:path")
                .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); } ) 
                .attr("d", arc);        
        arcs.append("svg:text")            
                .attr("transform", function(d) {                  
                d.innerRadius = 0;
                d.outerRadius = r;
                return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";   
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")           
            .text(function(d, i) { return data[i].label; });       
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```